# After changing state, content is not rerendering

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state

I am using React hooks (new to hooks) and today got a bug. After changing state, content is not re-rendering as it should be. Here's the code:

```
const App = () => {
    const [messeges, UpdataMesseges] = useState([]);


    //here's the code for updating the state, but even after changing the state it's not
    //re-rendering the content on the page.
    const sendMessege = (user, messege) => {
      UpdataMesseges((prevState) => {
        prevState.push({user: user, content: messege});
        console.log(messeges); //here it logs that state is changed (previously)
        return prevState;
      });
    }

    console.log(messeges);

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Header /> 
            <Chat>
                {
                  messeges.map(obj => <Messege content={obj.content} user="A" key={obj.content} />)
                }
            </Chat>
                {console.log(messeges)} {/*<----- Nothing gets logged even on state change*/}
            <Control>
                <Btn click={() => sendMessege('A', 'blah bla')} >blah</Btn>
            </Control>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You are mutating existing state object. You must return new array object. You can accomplish this by spreading in existing state into new array and appending the new object at the end.

```
const sendMessege = (user, messege) => {
  UpdataMesseges((prevState) => {
    return [...prevState, { user: user, content: messege }];
  });
}
```

If you want to log state updates use an effect with the state you want to log in the dependency array.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(messeges);
}, [messeges]);
```

Answer (score 0):

try

`UpdataMesseges((prevState) => {
    prevState.push({user: user, content: messege});
    return {...prevState}; // << chage this line on sendMessege method
});`